# Issue while inserting count vectorizer results to the dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, countvectorizer

I have a dataframe with shape `(4237, 19)` and then other dataframe with the shape `(4237, 6)`, I need to combine both these dataframes column wise, so technically resultant dataframe should be of the shape `(4237, 25)` but am getting as `(5524, 25)`. Am not able to understand the issue.

Code which I have used.

```
social_media_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(lowercase=True)

train_social_media_vector = social_media_vectorizer.fit_transform(x_train["social_media"].values.astype("U"))
test_social_media_vector = social_media_vectorizer.transform(x_test["social_media"].values.astype('U'))

print(x_train.shape)
print(x_test.shape)

train_social_media_df = pd.DataFrame(train_social_media_vector.todense(), columns=social_media_vectorizer.get_feature_names_out())
test_social_media_df = pd.DataFrame(test_social_media_vector.todense(), columns=social_media_vectorizer.get_feature_names_out())
x_train = pd.concat([x_train, train_social_media_df], axis=1)
x_test = pd.concat([x_test, test_social_media_df], axis=1)

print("="*100)
print(x_train.shape)
print(x_test.shape)

print("="*100)
print(social_media_vectorizer.vocabulary_)
```

Result

```
(4237, 19)
(1816, 19)
====================================================================================================
(5524, 25)
(3058, 25)
====================================================================================================
{'facebook': 0, 'linkedin': 2, 'twitter': 4, 'instagram': 1, 'youtube': 5, 'producthunt': 3}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the shape of `train_social_media_vector.todense()` is (4237, 6)? It's seems to be (1287, 6)

Try to `ignore_index=True`:

```
x_train = pd.concat([x_train, train_social_media_df], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
x_test = pd.concat([x_test, test_social_media_df], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Yeah, it is (4237,6). If it would have been (1287,6), then 1287 would be added to test data as well which will make it to (3103,25), right?

Comment: What is the shape of your original dataframe (before train_test_split)?

Comment: It is (6053, 29). I have dropped some columns which are not useful.

Comment: And try to replace `todense` by `toarray`

Comment: It is giving correct result when am doing `.reset_index(drop=True)` on `x_train` before `.concat` function but `ignore_index=True` is not giving the same result.

Comment: OK. I think I understood. Try: `train_social_media_df = pd.DataFrame(train_social_media_vector.todense(), columns=social_media_vectorizer.get_feature_names_out(), index=xtrain.index)`. Now you can concat without ignore_index.

Answer (score 0):

Check indexes of `x_train` and `x_test` before doing concat. I assume they have different indexes than the other ones. All rows are joined by the same index when doing concatenation. Missing rows will be filled with NaNs by default. If you do not care about indexes at all, simply drop them with `.reset_index(drop=True)` before doing concat, or ignore them with `ignore_index=True` in calling `pd.concat()`. See @Corralien 's answer above.